# Does Websphere TAI serve as a JAAS login module

Tags: api, websphere, jaas

I am trying to secure the APIs. The authentication is done via Websphere TAI and Active Directory.

Then I put the @RolesAllowed before my API method. It doesn't seem to work. Does the TAI serves as a JAAS login module? Don't see a clear answer at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0508_benantar/0508_benantar.html